# Selecting and displaying certain items from list based on specific property

Tags: c#

i have a list of objects saved in a text file that I can display onto a form. However now I need a button that will only display certain objects from the list based on a property, in my case brand. Below is the code I've been trying to use but cant get it to work.

```
   private void brandToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Car> BrandSelect = new List<Car>(cars);

        var SelectBrand = from c in BrandSelect
                         where c.Brand == textBox1.Text
                         select c;

        DisplayCar();
    }
```

Underneath is the full code, in case more information is needed, thanks for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Car_Manager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    string currentfile;
    Car c;
    int curIndex = -1;
    List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        c = new Car();
        saveFileDialog1.CreatePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "myText";
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter =
            "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    }

    public void clearForm()
    {
        txtBrand.Text = "";
        txtModel.Text = "";
        txtYear.Text = "";
        txtPrice.Text = "";
        txtNumMiles.Text = "";
        txtInformation.Text = "";
        radAutomatic.Checked = false;
        radManual.Checked = false;
        radConvertible.Checked = false;
        radCoupe.Checked = false;
        radEstate.Checked = false;
        radHatchback.Checked = false;
        radHPV.Checked = false;
        radSaloon.Checked = false;
        radSUV.Checked = false;


    }

    private void DisplayCar()
    {
        txtBrand.Text = c.Brand;
        txtModel.Text = c.Model;
        txtYear.Text = c.Year;
        txtPrice.Text = c.Price;
        txtNumMiles.Text = c.NumMiles;
        DisplayBody();
        DisplayGear();
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Information.Count(); i++)
            str += c.Information[i] + "\r\n";
        txtInformation.Text = str;

    }

    private void FormToObject()
    {
        c.Brand = txtBrand.Text;
        c.Model = txtModel.Text;
        c.Year = txtYear.Text;
        c.Price = txtPrice.Text;
        c.NumMiles = txtNumMiles.Text;
        BodyCheck();
        GearCheck();
    }

    private void BodyCheck()
    {
        if (radHatchback.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radHatchback.Text; }

        else if (radHPV.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radHPV.Text; }

        else if (radSUV.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radSUV.Text; }

        else if (radSaloon.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radSaloon.Text; }

        else if (radConvertible.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radConvertible.Text; }

        else if (radCoupe.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radCoupe.Text; }

        else if (radEstate.Checked == true)
        { c.Body = radEstate.Text; }

    }

    private void DisplayBody()
    {
        if (c.Body == "Hatchback")
        { radHatchback.PerformClick(); }

        else if (c.Body == "HPV")
        { radHPV.PerformClick(); }

        else if (c.Body == "SUV")
        { radSUV.PerformClick(); }

        else if (c.Body == "Convertible")
        { radConvertible.PerformClick(); }

        else if (c.Body == "Saloon")
        { radSaloon.PerformClick(); }

        else if (c.Body == "Coupe")
        { radSaloon.PerformClick(); }

        else if (c.Body == "Estate")
        { radEstate.PerformClick(); }
    }

    private void GearCheck()
    {
        if (radAutomatic.Checked == true)
        { c.GearBox = radAutomatic.Text; }

        else if (radManual.Checked == true)
        { c.GearBox = radManual.Text; }
    }

    private void DisplayGear()
    {
        if (c.GearBox == "Manual")
        { radManual.PerformClick(); }

        else if (c.GearBox == "Automatic")
        { radAutomatic.PerformClick(); }
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();            
        currentfile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        saveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;            
        Stream s1 = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();            
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s1);

        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
        {              
            string str = reader.ReadLine();
            Car c = new Car();
            c.ReadString(str);
            cars.Add(c);
        }

        curIndex = 0;
        c = cars[curIndex];
        DisplayCar();
        reader.Close();
    }

    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save everything in a dialog box
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        // Open the file and save the information
        Stream textOut = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textOut);

        FormToObject();
           string str = c.GetToString();
            writer.WriteLine(str);
            writer.Close();

    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the file with the current file name
        FileStream f1 = new FileStream(currentfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(f1);
        // get the object into a string
        FormToObject();

        StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(f1);
        cars.ForEach(file.WriteLine);
        file.Close();


    }

    private void btnAddInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c.Information.Add(txtAddInfo.Text);
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Information.Count(); i++)
            str += c.Information[i] + "\r\n";
        txtInformation.Text = str;
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtInformation.Text = "";
    }

    private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnPreviousCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curIndex--;
        if (curIndex < 0)

            curIndex = cars.Count - 1;
        c = cars[curIndex];
        DisplayCar();
    }

    private void btnNextCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curIndex++;
        if (curIndex >= cars.Count)

            curIndex = 0;
        c = cars[curIndex];
        DisplayCar();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int a = cars.Count;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(cars[2]);
    }

    private void btnEditCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBrand.ReadOnly = false;
        txtModel.ReadOnly = false;
        txtYear.ReadOnly = false;
        txtPrice.ReadOnly = false;
        txtNumMiles.ReadOnly = false;
        txtAddInfo.ReadOnly = false;

    }

    private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void brandToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Car> BrandSelect = new List<Car>(cars);

        var SelectBrand = from c in BrandSelect
                         where c.Brand == textBox1.Text
                         select c;

        DisplayCar();
    }

    private void yearToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}

class Car
{
    //List of properties
    private string brand;
    private string model;
    private string year;
    private string price;
    private string numMiles;
    private string body;
    private string gearbox;
    private List<string> information;

    //Constructor

    public Car() //Default Constructor
    {
        brand = "Unknown";
        model = "Unknown";
        year = "Unknown";
        price = "Unknown";
        numMiles = "Unknown";
        information = new List<string>();
    }

    public Car(string str)
    {
        information = new List<string>();
        ReadString(str);
    }

    public void ReadString(string str)
    {
        string[] words = str.Split('|');
        int Nwords = words.Count();
        brand = words[0];
        model = words[1];
        year = words[2];
        price = words[3];
        numMiles = words[4];
        body = words[5];
        gearbox = words[6];
        information.Clear();
        for (int i = 7; i < Nwords; i++)
            information.Add(words[i]);
    }

    //Methods
    public string Brand
    {
        get { return brand; }
        set { brand = value; }
    }

    public string Model
    {
        get { return model; }
        set { model = value; }
    }

    public string Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        set { year = value; }
    }

    public string Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    public string NumMiles
    {
        get { return numMiles; }
        set { numMiles = value; }
    }

    public string Body
    {
        get { return body; }
        set { body = value; }
    }

    public string GearBox
    {
        get { return gearbox; }
        set { gearbox = value; }
    }

    public List<string> Information
    {
        get { return information; }
        set { information = value; }
    }

    public string GetToString()
    {
        string str = "";
        str += brand + "|";
        str += model + "|";
        str += year + "|";
        str += price + "|";
        str += numMiles + "|";
        str += body + "|";
        str += gearbox + "|";
        for (int i = 0; i < information.Count(); i++)
            str += information[i] + "|";
        return str;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: "been trying to use but cant get it to work. " <-- you need to elaborate so we don't have to guess.  What isn't working, *specifically*?

Comment: 1) Too much code. Way too much. 2) Do you already have a LoadCarFromText() somewhere?  You'll need it.

Comment: I load in the the objects and store them in a list using the code under openToolStripMenuItem_Click(). It opens the text file and reads the text.

Comment: I don't see how that answers either of our questions.

Comment: To roryyap, I'm not sure if the code im using has actually selected the specific objects based on the brand name entered. I think this because when i used brandselect.count it showed there being 5 items rather than 2.

Comment: Im sure you did not mean `var SelectBrand = from c in BrandSelect ...`.

Comment: Do you ever clear your textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I noticed:

```
private void brandToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // You already have list of cars, this line will copy your list
    // into a new one, which is unnecessary work (you don't use it later).
    // You don't need this:
    List<Car> BrandSelect = new List<Car>(cars);

    // the "c" here is not the "c" that is the field of your form
    // it's a part of the syntax of linq query
    var SelectBrand = from c in BrandSelect
                     where c.Brand == textBox1.Text
                     select c;

    // This method displays what is in the field "c" (this.c)
    // ... and the content of "c" didn't change at all
    DisplayCar();
}
```

the code here should be, for example:

```
private void brandToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //beware this can be null
     this.c = (from a in this.cars 
               where a.Brand == textBox1.Text 
               select a).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

[[msdn] introduction to linq queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx)

Comment: So does the above code find the specific items and then store them, or does it edit the current list so only those can be displayed?

Comment: My code finds the first car in the list "cars" that has "Brand" equal to "textBox1.Text" and then puts it into the field "c" of your form, since it's what your "DisplayCar" method is actually displaying. It does not store anything other than that.

Comment: Ok thanks i've got it now. If there were more than one object with the same "brand", how could i show this? Would i need to create another list to store these and then use the previous and next buttons to cycle through?

Comment: the previous-next approach is a good idea. Or you could use some sort of grid/list (e.g.DataGridView, ListView) to show the whole result. And yes, you'd need to create another list with the result and store it somehow (for example as a property or a field) or pass it as a parameter to the method that "displays" it.